# What are differences between { default as name } and { name as default } when exporting js modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I was taking a look to the `swiper.esm.js` from Swiper.js (source copied [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fw4zj8qk/) for reference), and the first line is

```
export { default as Swiper, default } from './core/core.js';
```

while the following are of the form:

```
export { default as Virtual } from './modules/virtual/virtual.js';
```

and in MDN docs i can find that also something like

```
export { Something as default }
```

is possible. So I can currently see the following syntaxes:

```
export { Something as default }
export { default as Something }
export { default as Something, default }
```

What are the difference between the 3?

Comment: It should become pretty clear when you try to _import_ from modules with those exports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Import name `Something` from `...`, 
//   re-export as this module's default export
export { Something as default } from '...';

// Import default export from `...`, 
//   re-export as `Something` from this module
export { default as Something } from '...';

// Import default export from `...`, 
//   re-export it as `Something` from this module 
//   and this module's default export
export { default as Something, default } from '...';
```

Comment: Really nicely put! I might just add something saying they're all examples of *export renaming*.

Comment: thank you. The last 'and this module's default export' is for sure correct but quite strange to me considering the source code where it's written: https://jsfiddle.net/fw4zj8qk/ that is the swiper.esm.js source code. So what would the default be here, that is exported in the last line of your answer?

Comment: @LucaReghellin It means that as an user of Swiper, doing `import Swiper from 'swiper';` and `import {Swiper} from 'swiper';` would be equivalent. This would be convenient if you wanted to import multiple things from the package without one looking special: `import {Swiper, Zoom, Grid} from 'swiper';` works, so does `import Swiper, {Zoom, Grid} from 'swiper';`.

Comment: @LucaReghellin - `export { default as Swiper, default } from './core/core.js';` re-exports the default export of `"./core/core.js"` as `Swiper` and also as `default`.

Comment: @AKX - Although you could just do `import Swiper, {Zoom, Grid} from 'swiper';`. So not really all that much more convenient, though more robust if you had a typo like `Swper`. (One of many reasons to use named exports, not defaults, but of course when importing you're stuck with what the source package did.)

Comment: off-topic: I'm importing swiper just like that, and webpack is not doing tree shake, so by analyzing the bundle, I can find all the modules! Also disabled sideEffects in package.json and added usedExports in optimizations, but still I get all the modules (300k++)... Any idea? Maybe related to my (at the moment) bad understanding of all the module thing?